# Error setting TTL index on collection : Session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

I know that there is many topic about this problem but any of those solved my problem.
I am actually trying to deploy my project on Heroku which is something new for me.

My project is a node.js based on Express API connected to a MongoDB database.
When I launch it in local with my database (Without login / password) I don't have this error, but when I connect it to the heroku database I get a :

```
Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : Session <MongoError: not authorized for query on app17713548.system.indexes>
```

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.6",
    "mongodb": "1.3.19",
    "mongoskin": "0.5.0",
    "MD5": "1.0.3",
    "connect-session": "*",
    "connect-mongo": "0.3.3",
    "geoip-lite": "1.0.10"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "0.8.19",
    "npm": "1.1.65"
}
```

And for the connection to my database I am using MongoSkin and the line is:

```
mongo.db(conf.dbLogin+':'+conf.dbPassword+'@'+conf.dbAddr+':'+conf.dbPort+'/'+conf.dbName+'?auto_reconnect=true', {w: 1});
```

Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: What is the actual string that is being passed into the `mongo.db()` function?

Comment: It is basically the form of: 

'mysql2://LOGIN:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DB_NAME?auto_reconnect=true'

Comment: Shouldn't "mysql2" be "mongo"?

Comment: The mongoskin docs say to use "mongo", not "mongodb".

Comment: No it is just a variable, instantiated like ->
mongo = require('mongoskin');

But it can also be
foo = require('mongoskin');

Comment: The connection URL must start with "mongo://", not "mongodb://".

Comment: Anyway the mongo or mongodb is auto generated in the beginning and that's why I didn't specify it in the beginning.
But I tried to manually specify it, with mongo or mongodb and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Perhaps your database user account does not have the appropriate privileges necessary to function normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't configure the session storage that was also under mongodb with the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your connection string is incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

var db = new mongodb.Db(conf.dbName, new mongodb.Server(conf.dbAddr, conf.dbPort, {auto_reconnect:true}), {w:1});    
db.open(function(error){
  if (error){
    //handle
    return;
  }
  db.authenticate(conf.dbLogin, conf.dbPassword, function(error){
    if (error){
      //handle
      return;
    }
    //you are now connected!
  });
});
```

Comment: No I use MongoSkin, I linked you the github repository of the project.
https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin